# Coloring of @param and @return with Listings

Tags: pdftex, listings, pseudocode

Here is a MWE of what I have, along with a screenshot

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{color,soul}                                % For text coloring and highlighting
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0} %for listings
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5} %for listings
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82} %for listings

\lstset{frame=tb,
   language=php,
   aboveskip=3mm,
   belowskip=3mm,
   showstringspaces=false,
   columns=flexible,
   basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
   numbers=none,
   numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
   keywordstyle=\color{blue},
   commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
   morecomment=[l][\color{magenta}]{\#},
   stringstyle=\color{mauve},
   breaklines=true,
   breakatwhitespace=true,
   tabsize=3
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
/*
 * If the target is a valid duck, connects this bread with duck's mouth.
 * @param target the target we are trying to feed
 * @pre if target is an ancestor of class Duck, calls feedDuck()
 * @pre if target is an ancestor of MyDad, calls goHomeDadUrDrunk()
 * @return value of feedDuck() or goHomeDadUrDrunk() upon success, return value
 * of FALSE otherwise.
*/
function feed (target){\ldots}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there any way to make the keywords `@param`, `@pre`, `@post`, and `@return` stand out more by making them a different color? (please ignore the `\ldots`, it should be `...`)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Simply add it as a keyword by adding the line `otherkeywords={@param,@pre,@post,@return}` to `lstset`. See below

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{color,soul}                                % For text coloring and highlighting
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0} %for listings
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5} %for listings
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82} %for listings

\lstset{frame=tb,
   language=php,
   aboveskip=3mm,
   belowskip=3mm,
   showstringspaces=false,
   columns=flexible,
   basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
   numbers=none,
   numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
   keywordstyle=\color{blue},
   otherkeywords={@param,@pre,@post,@return},
   commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
   morecomment=[l][\color{magenta}]{\#},
   stringstyle=\color{mauve},
   breaklines=true,
   breakatwhitespace=true,
   tabsize=3
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
/*
 * If the target is a valid duck, connects this bread with duck's mouth.
 * @param target the target we are trying to feed
 * @pre if target is an ancestor of class Duck, calls feedDuck()
 * @pre if target is an ancestor of MyDad, calls goHomeDadUrDrunk()
 * @return value of feedDuck() or goHomeDadUrDrunk() upon success, return value
 * of FALSE otherwise.
*/
function feed (target){\ldots}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```